# Collect values from DB, group matching values, count it and use in other code

Tags: php, mysql

This is what my `customers_basket` table looks like:

```
customers_id | products_id                         | basket_quantity
3            | 56:3121fefbe6043d6fc12e3b3de2c8fc38 | 3
3            | 56:fb4c9278fcfe6225b58c06711a7e62ef | 1
3            | 56:8e334fce09556108f5416e27154b6c27 | 1
3            | 52:f3b9f38e4ddd18035bc04cd264b0f052 | 1
```

This is the query I'm using:

```
$products_in_cart_query = "SELECT products_id FROM customers_basket WHERE customers_id = " . $_SESSION['customer_id'] ."";
$products_in_cart       = $db->Execute($products_in_cart_query);
$products_in_cart_model = $products_in_cart->fields['products_id'];
$products_in_cart_model = substr($products_in_cart_model, 0, strpos($products_in_cart_model, ":"));
```

The end result I get is 56,56,56,52

First of all, how do I use the first line's quantity field? I'd need to list that products_id 3 times since quantity is 3. Therefore, the end result needs to be: 56,56,56,56,56,52
or, for easier understanding (56,56,56),56,56,52

And second, how do I count how many same values I have? In this case, I have 5x56 and 1x52. I need to use those counts in my further calculation.

EDIT: further calculations explained
I need to know how many of each product_id I have and then run something like this:

```
foreach(product_id) {
    $shipping_cost += FIXED_VALUE * basket_qty;
}
```

Comment: Do you really need 5 lines of data starting with 56, or do you just need to get the sum of the quantities?

Answer (score 0):

To get the basket quantity, you have to select it.  It would be best if the first portion of the product ID was stored in a separate column, rather than having to do messy operations like substringing.

Query 1: 2-character codes and corresponding quantities

```
SELECT SUBSTR(products_id, 1, 2) AS product_code, basket_quantity
  FROM Customers_Basket
 WHERE customers_id = 3;
```

Query 2: 2-character codes and summed quantities

```
SELECT product_code, SUM(basket_quantity) AS total_quantity
  FROM (SELECT SUBSTR(products_id, 1, 2) AS product_code, basket_quantity
          FROM Customers_Basket
         WHERE customers_id = 3
       )
 GROUP BY product_code;
```

If you really, really, really desperately want 3 rows of data for the product ID `56:3121fefbe6043d6fc12e3b3de2c8fc38`, then you have to know ways to generate rows.  They're truly painful in the absence of convenient SQL support (so much so, that you'd do better to select a row in PHP with the quantity and then generate the appropriate number of rows in your array in the client-side (PHP) code).  I'm going to assume that some variation on these queries will get you the information you want.

Comment: uhm... SUBSTR - I'm not sure if this will work since I have some 1-digit product_id, some 2-digit and some 3-digit. That's why I took it out of the sql. Basically, everything after the colon is auto-generated and irrelevant, but the first 1/2/3 digits are the actual product_id.
Also, SUM(basket_quantity) - won't that return 6? I need to know how many 56s I have and how many 52s...

Comment: sorry, spoke too soon. But, the main part of the question: how do i COUNT those IDs? How do I echo how many of each I have? I would probably need some for each, right? Please see my original post edit.

Comment: @user1078494 `SUBSTRING_INDEX(products_id,':',1)` will give you the product code and `SUBSTRING_INDEX(products_id,':',-1)` will give you the remaining part.

Comment: I very strongly recommend you have the auto-generated stuff put into a separate column; it will make your life so much easier.  It is not a good idea to mix two different values in a single column; and the difficulties you're having now are just one indication of why not.